# Kinesis agent failing to start

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to setup a kinesis agent on an Amazon EC2 instance which is supposed to be preinstalled.

But when I run the command:

```
sudo service aws-kinesis-agent start
```

It gives an error.. can someone help?

Comment: What is the error message. Did you follow the steps on [Writing to Amazon Kinesis Data Streams Using Kinesis Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/writing-with-agents.html#config-start)?